Creating a POSTGRESQL function that does a search based on table name and ID
I'm attempting to make a function that I can call from an app that returns the results of the entire tables searched. I'm expecting the function to return all the columns of the users table and the variable defined table that it joins to with results that are limited on the user ID which is a uuid.
Here is the closest I've come to solving it. I've tried a few variants, but even when I can get SQL to accept the variable, it won't call it successfully when I attempt to query it.
create or replace function DynamicTableSearch(Table_Name varchar,User_ID uuid)
returns setof tmp_table as $$

declare _userid uuid;
declare _tablename varchar;
result tmp_table;
BEGIN
    SELECT 'efaad10a-6e0b-4b52-8d55-2c4eefd84cd5' INTO _userid;
    select '"Table_Name"' into _tablename;

    --DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_table;
    --CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table AS
    SELECT * FROM public."Users" u
    join public._tablename x on u."id" = x."UsersID"
    into tmp_table
    WHERE   id = _userid;
return tmp_table
 --RETURN tmp_table;
END $$ language plpgsql


That is impossible. Find a different solution.

You need dynamic SQL for that.
create or replace function dynamictablesearch(table_name text, arg_user_id uuid)
returns setof tmp_table as $$
DECLARE 
    dynsql text := 'SELECT * FROM public."Users" u
      join public.%I x on u."id" = x."UsersID"
      WHERE id = %L';
BEGIN
    return query execute format(dynsql, table_name, arg_user_id);
END $$ language plpgsql;

Notes:

You need to first define type tmp_table as the record type of the
two joined tables;
Be careful, the function is SQL injection prone;
Better do not use uppercase letters in column names and identifiers

Unrelated but I am not sure that the use of dynamic table names is a good idea at all. Maybe review your data design?
